# How to assert mutex is acquired in C++?

Tags: c++, clang, locking

In abseil, leveldb and other C++ projs, I often see macro (eg: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/1ae9b71c474628d60eb251a3f62967fe64151bb2/absl/base/thread_annotations.h#L141)

```
#if defined(__clang__)

#define THREAD_ANNOTATION_ATTRIBUTE__(x) __attribute__((x))
#else
#define THREAD_ANNOTATION_ATTRIBUTE__(x)  // no-op
#endif

#ifndef ASSERT_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK
#define ASSERT_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK(...) \
  THREAD_ANNOTATION_ATTRIBUTE__(assert_exclusive_lock(__VA_ARGS__))
#endif
```

If we expand it, it should be `__attribute__((exclusive_locks_required(mutex)))`. I'm curious, how does it checks and asserts mutex is acquired at runtime? Since I don't see such functionality implemented in C POSIX APIs.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually checked at runtime at all, and not just there as a hint for static analyzers and stuff?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html “*Clang Thread Safety Analysis* is a C++ language extension which *warns about potential race conditions* in code. *The analysis is completely static (i.e. compile-time)*; there is no run-time overhead.”

Comment: Here it says check goes at runtime: https://gitlab.mpi-klsb.mpg.de/eweyulu/quic-chrome/-/blob/465addbb95e7d8e33c7d0b3d36a77f0465076810/base/thread_annotations.h#L175 @user2864740

Comment: @Dentiny The highlighted text in the link states “*Documents functions that* dynamically check..”; it does not make any claim about *checking at* runtime. I also generally put more weight on proper documentation, including high-level synopsis and design overview, than scattered comments.